# Error en configuracion de Spring Security y Jpa

Tags: spring, jpa

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación rápida donde tengo que activar la autenticación.

Mi configuracion del spring security es esta :

```
package com.grupocoder.peliculas.util;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import com.grupocoder.peliculas.Servicios.JpaUsuarioDetailServicio;
import com.grupocoder.peliculas.auth.handler.LoginSuccessHandler;

public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private LoginSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JpaUsuarioDetailServicio userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/listar").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().successHandler(successHandler).loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error_403");

    }



    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("USER DETAIL SERVICE"+userDetailsService);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Pero me marca este error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:244) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:198) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:90) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
```

alguna idea por mas que leo por todos lados dicen que es por autenticacion de memoria pero yo lo estoy haciendo por modo de jpa asi que no entiendo porque pasa esto

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que las contraseñas en tu base de datos están guardadas en el formato correcto? Usando bCrypt deberían todas empezar por algo como `$2a$10$...`

Comment: si amigo $2a$10$HQmfGM6wJMcoMQdYin4vxOzOPBLI1jq/Ha8/L6UcXCGEcVMXJ0hxm  

un ejemplo seria este

Comment: relacionada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654143/spring-security-5-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Spring 5.X se asocia un prefijo a las contraseñas guardadas, algo como:

```
{bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG
```

De [su blog](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-format) leemos:

> ## Password Storage Updated
>
> Password storage has undergone a major overhaul to provide more secure
>   defaults and the ability to migrate how passwords are stored. The
>   default PasswordEncoder is now DelegatingPasswordEncoder which is a
>   non-passive change. This change ensures that passwords are now encoded
>   using BCrypt by default, allows for validating passwords in old
>   formats, and allows for upgrading the password storage in the future.

Una traducción aproximada es:

> El almacenamiento de contraseñas ha sufrido un gran cambio para
>   proveer más seguridad y la habilidad de migrar cómo las contraseñas
>   son guardadas. Ahora el codificador por defecto es de la clase
>   `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`, lo que no es un cambio *pasivo*. Este
>   cambio asegura que las contraseñas se guardan por defecto con BCrypt,
>   permitiendo validar formatos más viejos y actualizar las contraseñas a
>   formatos más nuevos.

Esto significa que debes declarar el PasswordEncoder declarando explícitamente que, ante la falta de identificador (el prefijo `{bcrypt}`), se usará ese codificador por defecto:

```
String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
PasswordEncoder default=new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

// Para validar
Map encoders = new HashMap<>();
encoders.put(idForEncode, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
encoders.put("noop", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
encoders.put("pbkdf2", new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder());
encoders.put("scrypt", new SCryptPasswordEncoder());
encoders.put("sha256", new StandardPasswordEncoder());

// En el constructor le pasamos cuál debe usar para codificar
DelegatingPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder =
    new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoders);
// por defecto que use también BCrypt
passwordEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(default);
```

Comment: realmente me funciono no me habia percatado que no tenia las inyecciones de las dependencias por ende la configuracion que estaba haciendo no tenia efecto .. tube que agregar los autowired y las etiquetas de configuracion de spring security